# Do I need to halt in order to really turn power off?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I tried `shutdown -f now`, thinking it will do a full power off sequence.
Instead, it ends with

> *Checking battery state...

and just hangs there.

Should I add `-h` switch to fully take power off, or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're [supposed](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) to run `shutdown -h`, or its alias `halt`, to turn off the system; on some machines you need `shutdown -P` or `poweroff`. In fact, without `-h` (or `-P` or `-r`), `shutdown` is not supposed to turn the computer off, it's supposed to drop into single user mode (at least with the traditional Linux SysVinit, I don't know how compatible [Ubuntu's upstart](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/shutdown.8.html) is).

This doesn't preclude another issue which would cause `poweroff` not to actually power down the computer. [Not-fully-supported ACPI is a common culprit.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/do-i-need-to-halt-in-order-to-really-turn-power-off/10697#10697)

Answer (score 2):

Could be an ACPI issue.  Look if your distro provides an ACPI package for your brand of laptop.

It's possible this message could also come from a script executing at shutdown.  Find out how your distro handles shutdown scripts and you might be able to edit that particular script to not check battery state on shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care you can try shutdown with -n, to skip init stuff